# ffmpeg how add header info into pcm?

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, pcm

I use this cmd convert s16le to pcmu8, but will lost header info.

```sh
ffmpeg -i s16le.wav -f u8 pcmu8.wav
ffmpeg -i pcmu8.wav
# pcmu8.wav: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I want known, how add this header info into pcmu8.wav?

It should be this:

```sh
ffmpeg -i pcmu8.wav
#Input #0, wav, from 'pcmu8.wav':
#  Duration: 00:13:39.20, bitrate: 64 kb/s
#  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first command is outputting to a raw bitstream, not a WAV, so adding a header won't help. Instead use

```
ffmpeg -i s16le.wav -c:a pcm_u8 pcmu8.wav
```